# Erlang: Loop through list - badarg

Tags: list, erlang

My problem is that in a function where I use the lists:any function it can never finish looking through the given list. Below is the error that I get:

```
{badarg,
[{genserver,request,3,
     [{file,
          [99,58,47,85,115,101,114,115,47,68,97,118,105,100,47,
           68,101,115,107,116,111,112,47,71,106,111,114,100,32,
           102,114,195,131,194,165,110,32,103,114,117,110,100,
           101,110,47,103,101,110,115,101,114,118,101,114,46,101,
           114,108]},
      {line,33}]},
 {lists,any,2,[{file,"lists.erl"},{line,1223}]},
 {server,loop,2,
     [{file,
          [99,58,47,85,115,101,114,115,47,68,97,118,105,100,47,
           68,101,115,107,116,111,112,47,71,106,111,114,100,32,
           102,114,195,131,194,165,110,32,103,114,117,110,100,
           101,110,47,115,101,114,118,101,114,46,101,114,108]},
      {line,27}]},
 {genserver,loop,2,
     [{file,
          [99,58,47,85,115,101,114,115,47,68,97,118,105,100,47,
           68,101,115,107,116,111,112,47,71,106,111,114,100,32,
           102,114,195,131,194,165,110,32,103,114,117,110,100,
           101,110,47,103,101,110,115,101,114,118,101,114,46,101,
           114,108]},
      {line,13}]}]}}
```

I populate the list with the following code:

```
channels = channels ++ [{Channel}]
```

Where **Channel** is a string and **channels** is initialised to **[ ]**. Finally #27 below is what's causing the error:

```
#24 loop(St, {Nick, PID, disconnect}) ->
#25     case lists:keymember(Nick, 1, St#server_st.users) of
#26         false   -> {{error, user_not_connected, "Nick doesn't exist on server."}, St};      
#27         true -> case lists:any(fun(F) -> genserver:request(F, {Nick, PID, is_member}) end, St#server_st.channels) of
#28             true -> {{error, leave_channels_first, "Still in a channel."}, St};
#29             false -> {ok, St#server_st{users = lists:delete({Nick, PID}, St#server_st.users)}}
#30         end
#31     end;
```

Where **F** is used as a PID. What I could find its an issue with how I populate the list but no matter how I twist and turn it I end up with identical results.

Comment: The error report says that you use a bad argument in the function genserver:request/3 while the line you show calls genserver:request/2. Verify your post, and it would be better if you give more context, specially the code around line 27 of server.erl.

Comment: @Pascal No that's correct, genserver/2(PID, Tuple) calls genserver/3(PID, Tuple, Timeout). Don't see how more of the function would help the issue but edited the post with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is from the *genserver:request/2* call, check that the parameters passed are valid for the function definition. For example, from the information above, F in line 27 will be a tuple containing a string and not a PID.

Comment: Can I convert **F** into a PID, or do I need to store it as a PID to begin with? Tried to convert **F** into a PID using the list_to_pid function but it still doesn't accept it.

Comment: I think it is good idea to store it as a PID. You can check if the process is still alive before using it by calling process_info/1.

Comment: Couldn't get it to work when I stored it as a pid but storing it as an atom worked better. However row #27 is still causing issues, makes the function exit with "Error in process <0.119.0> with exit value: {{case_clause,false},[{genserver,loop,2,[{file, ..." which I find odd since I catch the false clause so it should exit with the given tuple.

Comment: It looks like line #27 is in server:loop/2. Instead you should check genserver:loop/2 as the error message suggests.

Comment: The genserver:loop/2 is what's keeping the server running and the function have been thoroughly tested so it's something I'm doing inside the server that's causing the issue. If I remove the whole second case statement from my function and just replace it with **{ok, St#server_st{users = lists:delete({Nick, PID}, St#server_st.users)}}** it work just fine so that's why I believe it's row #27 that's the issue.

Comment: Solved it, was an issue with the lists:any function, returned the tuple incorrect which made genserver weird.